# When and why to use self.__dict__ instead of self.variable

Tags: python, class, dictionary, oop

I'm trying to understand some code which is using this class below:

```
class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.client = kwargs.get('client')
        self.request = kwargs.get('request')
    ...

    def to_dict(self):
        data = dict()

        for key in iter(self.__dict__): # <------------------------ this
            if key in ('client', 'request'):
                continue

            value = self.__dict__[key]
            if value is not None:
                if hasattr(value, 'to_dict'):
                    data[key] = value.to_dict()
                else:
                    data[key] = value
        return data
```

I understand that it gets keyword arguments passed to the `Base` class like for example, `Base(client="foo", request="bar")`.

My confusion is, why is it using `self.__dict__` which turns variables inside `__init__` to a dict (e.g `{"client": "foo", "request": "bar"}`) instead of just calling them by `self.client` & `self.request` inside other methods? When and why I should use `self.__dict__` instead?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost all of the time, you shouldn't use `self.__dict__`.

If you're accessing an attribute like `self.client`, i.e. the attribute name is known and fixed, then the only difference between that and `self.__dict__['client']` is that the latter won't look up the attribute on the class if it's missing on the instance. There is very rarely any reason to do this, but the difference is demonstrated below:

```py
>>> class A:
...     b = 3 # class attribute, not an instance attribute
... 
>>> A.b # the class has this attribute
3
>>> a = A()
>>> a.b # the instance doesn't have this attribute, fallback to the class
3
>>> a.__dict__['b'] # the instance doesn't have this attribute, but no fallback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'b'
```

The main use-case for `self.__dict__` is when you *don't* want to access a fixed, known attribute name. In almost all code, you *always* know which attribute you want to access; and if you do need to look something up dynamically using an unknown string, you should create a dictionary yourself, and write `self.that_dict[key]` instead of `self.__dict__[key]`.

So the only times you should really use `__dict__` is when you are writing code which needs to work regardless of which attributes the instance might have; i.e. you specifically want code which will work even if you change the class's structure or its attribute names, or code which will work across multiple classes with different structures. I'll show one example below.

#### The `__repr__` method

The `__repr__` method is meant to return a string representing the instance, for the programmer's convenience when using a REPL. For debugging/testing purposes this string usually contains information about the object's state. Here's a common way to implement it:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Foo({!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(self.foo, self.bar, self.baz)
```

This means if you write `obj = Foo(1, 'y', True)` to create an instance, then `repr(obj)` will be the string `"Foo(1, 'y', True)"`, which is convenient because it shows the instance's entire state, and also the string itself is Python code which creates an instance with the same state.

But there are a few issues with the above implementation: we have to change it if the class's attributes change, it won't give useful results for instances of subclasses, and we have to write lots of similar code for different classes with different attributes. If we use `__dict__` instead, we can solve all of those problems:

```py
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}({})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__,
            ', '.join('{}={!r}'.format(k, v) for k, v in self.__dict__.items())
        )
```

Now `repr(obj)` will be `Foo(foo=1, bar='y', baz=True)`, which also shows the instance's entire state, and is also executable Python code. This generalised `__repr__` method will still work if the structure of `Foo` changes, it can be shared between multiple classes via inheritance, and it returns executable Python code for any class whose attributes are accepted as keyword arguments by `__init__`.

Answer (score 2):

`__dict__` holds *all* of the variables in the class. Take the following class:

```py
class A():
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

    def new_var(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

Then in this case, notice:

```
a = A('var1')
print(a.__dict__) # {'foo': 'var1'}

b = A('var1')
b.new_var('var2')
b.foobar = 'var3'
print(b.__dict__) # {'foo': 'var1', 'bar': 'var2', 'foobar': 'var3'}
```

In your case you could do either or. `__dict__` is a great way to grab all of the variables that are part of that class at the current instance in which it is called. You can check out the documentation on `__dict__` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes).

Comment: I get this part, but what is the real world use case for it? why would i use it instead of just calling by `self.name`

Comment: A good example would be the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, where it allows you to save classes to file and load them for later use -- in this case, `pickle` will use a class `__dict__` to serialize the class into a `.p` file. Another example would be if you initialize some class from an external module and you are not sure what the properties of that class is... printing `class.__dict__` is an easy way to check out the variables accessible to you.

Comment: I also invite you to do `A.__dict__` with the example class above (not `a.__dict__`). You will notice `__dict__` will return all of the functions in the given class + some extra things. All in all, `__dict__` can be used for a multitude of things in the real world, however as it is showcased here or in the documentation, it's only one tool in the thousands that are accessible in Python.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

```
self.x # is equivalent to 
getattr(a, 'x')
```

but `self.x`  is equivalent to  `(ancestors.__dict__ | A.__dict__ | self.__dict__)['x']`

usage:

```
if A.__dict__.get('x'):

if self.__dict__.get('x'):

if getattr(self, 'x', None):
if hasattr(self, 'x') and self.x:
```

test:

```
class A():
    x=1                   #     'x' in A.__dict__        
    def set_x_2(self):    # 'set_x_2' in A.__dict__  
        self.x=2          #     'x' in self.__dict__

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):    # '__setattr__' in A.__dict__  
        print(f'__setattr__ {name}, {value}')
        super(A, self).__setattr__(name, value)

a=A()
print(isinstance(A, object)) # True
print(isinstance(a, object)) # True
a.x==1      # True
a.set_x_2() # print __setattr__ x, 2
a.x==2      # True
a.x=3       # print __setattr__ x, 3

class B(A):
    # 'x' not in self.__dict__
    # 'x' not in B.__dict__
    pass
b=B()
b.x==1 # True  

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property  # https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property
    def x(self):                    # 'x' in C.__dict__
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x              # '_x' in self.__dict__

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
c1=C()
c2=C()
c1.x=1
c2.x=2
print(c1.x, c2.x) # 1, 2
```

Comment: @Charles-Duffy  changed

Answer (score 0):

[**__dict__**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) is used when checking what instance variables(data attributes) an object has.

So, if there is `Person` class below:

```py
class Person:
    x1 = "Hello"
    x2 = "World"
    
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def test1(self):
        print(self.__dict__) # Here
        
    @classmethod
    def test2(cls):
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def test3():
        pass

obj = Person("John", 27)    
obj.test1() # Here
```

[**__dict__**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) gets `name` and `age` with their values in a dictionary as shown below:

```
{'name': 'John', 'age': 27} # Here
```

And, if **the new instance variable `gender`** is added after instanciation as shown below:

```py
# ...

obj= Person("John", 27)
obj.test1()  
obj.gender = "Male" # Here
obj.test1()
```

[**__dict__**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) gets `name`, `age` and `gender` with their values in a dictionary as shown below:

```
{'name': 'John', 'age': 27}
{'name': 'John', 'age': 27, 'gender': 'Male'} # Here
```